# What is the concept of Pending Intent? Why and when we use Pending Intent?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

My question is simple. What is the concept of Pending Intent? Why and when we use Pending Intents? Please also give code example if possible

Comment: You can go through these links: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2007/12/playing-with-intents.html http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: Pending Intent:- http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#pendingintent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Go through that For Details